# Django IntegrityError 'author_id' violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, forms

I don't know why Django raise IntegrityError when I try to post a comment form. It forces me to defin author and halp to `null=True` and `blank=True` but I don't want to. In my project, when someone post a comment, the author and the post (halp) attached must not be null.

1st: 'author_id' violates not-null constraint

2nd: 'halp_id' violates not-null constraint

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = [
        ('open', _('Ouvert')),
        ('deleted', _('Supprimé'))
    ]

    halp = models.ForeignKey("Halp", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    comment = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comment_child", null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='open')
    is_solution = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['halp', '-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.halp.title

    def get_text(self):
        return self.text[:20]
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control form-custom',
            'placeholder': _('Redigez une réponse ou un commentaire...')
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

views.py:

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = forms.CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        self.halp = Halp.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

        self.comment = Comment.objects.create(
            text=text,
            author=self.request.user,
            halp=self.halp,
        )

        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('forum:halp-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.halp.slug})
```

If anyone can help me, I think I have missed something. Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your **`form_valid(...)`** method as,

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = forms.CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.author = self.request.user
        comment.halp = Halp.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comment.save()
        self.object = comment
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('forum:halp-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['slug']})
```

Comment: Oh God thank you! Can you explain to me why I was wrong?

Comment: because you didn't set FK values ***correctly*** , The **`commit=False`** will create a *dummy model object* and you can attach/assign FK values. @Beno